# Xcode 5 with JGit repository

Tags: xcode, version-control, jgit

How can I use Xcode with a JGit repository instead of a Git repository? The checkout dialog offers only the types “Git” and “Subversion”.

If I try to open a JGit repository as a traditional Git type, the error message says “fatal: Unable to find remote helper“.

[image: Xcode's checkout dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode doesn't directly support a repo stored on S3 (it's something unique to JGit).

That said, you should be able to access a repo there by using a combination of [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/) and [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/). You will need to install FUSE (which allows the use of filesystems from userland) and then s3fs (to mount the S3 bucket) and then mount the bucket containing the repo somewhere on your local filesystem. Once that's done, you'll be able to reference it using the local filesystem mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

JGit is just a Jave interface to work with Git repositories, so there is no Jgit-Repository. Git repositories can be handled with Git or JGit, the resulting repository is identical.